# Assignment and else if statements

Tags: java

I am not to sure what the error is in my code but the order variable does not seem to initialise properly and hence my gui displays the wrong output, for example when cheese,tomato and chicken are selected it only displays Chicken with Tomato Tomato $12.75. Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class PizzaFrame extends JFrame 
{
// The following components are defined (but not created).
private JButton newButton, exitButton;
private JLabel priceLabel, grandTotalLabel;
private JCheckBox chkCheese, chkChicken, chkTomato;
private JTextArea jTA;

// Other values used throughout this frame
private double total, orderTotal, grandTotal;
private String order = "";
private static final String noOrder =  "Base price of basic pizza is $10.00";

// set up GUI
public PizzaFrame() 
{
    // Ensure there is a suitable title for the frame
    setTitle("Welcome to Mylo's Pizza world, please make an order");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    // Create the buttons for the user to click, and add them to the frame
    newButton = new JButton("New Order");
    exitButton = new JButton("Exit \t \n");
    add(newButton);
    add(exitButton);

    // Create the Check Boxes and add these to the frame.
    chkCheese = new JCheckBox("Cheese");
    chkChicken = new JCheckBox("Chicken");
    chkTomato = new JCheckBox("Tomato");
    add(chkCheese);
    add(chkChicken);
    add(chkTomato);


    priceLabel = new JLabel(noOrder);
    add(priceLabel);

    // Create the TextArea in which to display the progressive orders.
    jTA = new JTextArea(10,10);
    //JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(jTA);
    //jTA.setLineWrap(true);
    //scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    //scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    add(jTA);
    //add(scroller);

    // Create the lower Label which displays the       
    grandTotalLabel = new JLabel("Startup - No orders taken yet. Total: $0");
    add(grandTotalLabel);


    ButtonHandler event_handler = new ButtonHandler();
    newButton.addActionListener(event_handler);
    exitButton.addActionListener(event_handler);


    // create and register listeners for the JCheckBoxes
    CheckBoxHandler box_listener = new CheckBoxHandler();
    chkCheese.addItemListener(box_listener);
    chkChicken.addItemListener(box_listener);
    chkTomato.addItemListener(box_listener);

    //set the size of the frame
    setSize( 250, 310 );

} 


private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener 
{
    // start new order or exit on button event
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) 
    {
        orderTotal = total;
        grandTotal += orderTotal;
        //boolean action = false;
        if (event.getSource() == newButton) 
        {
            // TO BE COMPLETED
            order = "";
            chkCheese.setSelected (false);
            chkChicken.setSelected(false);
            chkTomato.setSelected(false);
            //String order_total = Double.toString(orderTotal);
            jTA.append(order + " $" + Double.toString(orderTotal) + "\n");



        }
        else if (event.getSource() == exitButton) 
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    } 
} 



private class CheckBoxHandler implements ItemListener 
{
    static final double CHEESE_COST = 2.75;
    static final double CHICKEN_COST = 4.00;
    static final double TOMATO_COST = 0.50;

// respond to checkbox events by adding cost of pizza topping options to price
    public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent event )
    {
            total = 10.00;
            // TO BE COMPLETED
            String selection = "";
            if (chkCheese.isSelected()) 
                total = total + CHEESE_COST;
            else if (chkChicken.isSelected()) 
                total = total + CHICKEN_COST;
            else if (chkTomato.isSelected()) 
                total = total + TOMATO_COST;



            if (chkCheese.isSelected() && chkChicken.isSelected() && chkTomato.isSelected()) 
            {
                selection = "Cheese with Chicken and Tomato ";
                order += selection;
            }
            else if(chkCheese.isSelected() && chkChicken.isSelected() && chkTomato.isSelected())
            {
                      //else
                          order += "Cheese with Chicken ";
            }
            else if(chkCheese.isSelected() && chkTomato.isSelected())
            {
                    //if (chkTomato.isSelected()) 
                        order += "Cheese with Tomato ";
            }

            else if (chkChicken.isSelected() && chkTomato.isSelected())
            {
                  //if (chkTomato.isSelected()) 
                      order += "Chicken with Tomato ";
            }
            else if(chkCheese.isSelected())
            {
                        order += "Cheese ";     
            }
            else if (chkChicken.isSelected())
            {
                      order += "Chicken ";
            }
            else if (chkTomato.isSelected())
            {
                      order += "Tomato ";
            }


        priceLabel.setText("Price of pizza is: $" +  Double.toString(total));
        grandTotalLabel.setText("Total income is: $" +  Double.toString(grandTotal));

    } 
} 

//----------------------------------------- Program Entry/Start point:

public static void main( String args[] ) 
{
    PizzaFrame pFrame = new PizzaFrame();
    pFrame.addWindowListener ( 

                                  // TO BE COMPLETED
            new WindowAdapter() 
            {   
                public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e) 
                {
                            System.exit(0); 
                }            
            }   

    );                          

    // Show the pizza frame ...
    pFrame.setVisible( true );
}
```

}

Comment: It would be faster if you post only the code block where you have the problem instead of the whole program.

Comment: Let's start with some debugging skills. First, you should use your IDE's debugger to step through the program and look at the values of your variables. If you are using a command-line compiler, you can add SOPs to display the values of variables at critical points. After you do this, let us know what you find and we will gladly help you figure out how to fix the problem.

Comment: Just so it's said...you could make this a whole lot simpler by examining the common pattern with how you figure out the items.  Like, say, have a list of toppings, and for each topping (in order, if you like) add it to the list if it's selected.  Then format the list like "*topping1* (with *topping2 if it's there* (and *topping3 if it's there*))"... you could even add to the list and tack on the extra cost at the same time.

Comment: Each of your items should be self contained objects, containing descriptions and prices, then it would simply be a process of iterating over a list of items to get the total and description...IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Else if quits, if a condition was fulfilled. You want the price to be the sum of all selected items, not just the first selected item.
There was a tiny mistake in your conditions for the text-display, too.

```
public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent event )
    {
            total = 10.00;
            // TO BE COMPLETED
            String selection = "";
            if (chkCheese.isSelected()) 
                total = total + CHEESE_COST;
            if (chkChicken.isSelected()) 
                total = total + CHICKEN_COST;
            if (chkTomato.isSelected()) 
                total = total + TOMATO_COST;



            if (chkCheese.isSelected() && chkChicken.isSelected() && chkTomato.isSelected()) 
            {
                selection = "Cheese with Chicken and Tomato ";
                order += selection;
            }
            else if(chkCheese.isSelected() && chkChicken.isSelected())
            {
                          order += "Cheese with Chicken ";
            }
            else if(chkCheese.isSelected() && chkTomato.isSelected())
            { 
                        order += "Cheese with Tomato ";
            }

            else if (chkChicken.isSelected() && chkTomato.isSelected())
            {
                      order += "Chicken with Tomato ";
            }
            else if(chkCheese.isSelected())
            {
                        order += "Cheese ";     
            }
            else if (chkChicken.isSelected())
            {
                      order += "Chicken ";
            }
            else if (chkTomato.isSelected())
            {
                      order += "Tomato ";
            }


        priceLabel.setText("Price of pizza is: $" +  Double.toString(total));
        grandTotalLabel.setText("Total income is: $" +  Double.toString(grandTotal));

    }
```